# shopify:extracting .json file using php

Tags: php, json, shopify

How to get the value of product's compare at price from `orders.json` file?

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/shopify.php';
//require_once 'csv.php';
$t="e94c1df5ef5c6b2b2e9d893a3be2eb35";
$sc = new ShopifyClient("cannon-25.myshopify.com", $t, API_KEY, SECRET);
if(isset($t)) {
    $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array('published_status'=>'published'));
    foreach($orders as order) {
        echo $order['name'];
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks!.

Comment: what problem are you having...?

Comment: I have installed one private app to my shopify store, now i want to get all the orders details by using my private app.i gor all the value s expect compare at price.

Comment: does the json file has compare price in it. I mean how do you get this compare price.

Comment: @ sfletche: Do you know shopofy? Thank you.

Comment: @Kapilgopinath: no it does not have, its have products.json file..

Comment: If anybody know about shopify? Then only can clarify my question.

Comment: Please update your title  to Shopify related

Answer (score 0):

The `compare_at_price` is part of a product, not an order, so it is available in **products.json**.

If you need access to the `compare_at_price` from **orders.json**, I would try first getting the `product_id` from [**orders.json**](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#index) and then retrieving the `compare_at_price` from [**products/#{id}.json**](http://docs.shopify.com/api/product#show).